# Unable to decrypt AES data using Obj-C that was encrypted using Java

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, encryption

I'm stuck trying to decrypt some AES encrypted data sent by a server to my app.

In order to distill the problem down I've written a small java program that emulates what the server is doing. It encrypts some test data using AES then encodes it as Base64:

```
AesCipherService cipherService  = new AesCipherService();
cipherService.setKeySize(128);

String stringKey = "2EE1F10212ADD4BE";
byte[] keyAsBytes =  stringKey.getBytes();

String text = "text to encrypt";
byte[] encryptedBytes    = cipherService.encrypt(text.getBytes(), keyAsBytes).getBytes();
String base64String      = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
System.out.println(base64String);

// Reverse the process to check can retrieve "text to encrypt":
byte[] bytesToDecode = Base64.decode(base64String);
byte[] decryptedBytes = cipherService.decrypt(bytesToDecode, keyAsBytes).getBytes();         
String decryptedString = new String(decryptedBytes);   
System.out.println(decryptedString);
```

When run this is the output:

> R5UBpP30YjX9Ae2HoPb2Rrfi5rQJY2d0ac1+zaIX5A4=
>
> text to encrypt

So I can successfully encrypt the data, print it out. Then if I unencrypt it the original text is displayed, so everything here is working fine.

Now here is my Obj-C code where I attempt to decrypt the data encrypted from the Java code. I've copied/pasted the encrypted data from the NetBeans IDE output window as the source data of the obj-c content to decrypt:

```
- (void) decryptData
{
    NSData* dataToDecrypt       = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString: @"R5UBpP30YjX9Ae2HoPb2Rrfi5rQJY2d0ac1+zaIX5A4="  options: 0];
    NSString* key               = @"2EE1F10212ADD4BE";

    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [dataToDecrypt length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          [dataToDecrypt bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
        NSData* unencryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
        Byte *unencryptedAsBytes = (Byte*)malloc(unencryptedData.length);
        memcpy(unencryptedAsBytes, [unencryptedData  bytes], unencryptedData.length);
        NSString *decryptedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[unencryptedData bytes]];
        NSLog(@"%@", decryptedString);
    }
}
```

When this is run the status is kCCSuccess and numBytesDecrypted is 32 (the same as dataLength) but the decrypted string is not "text to encrypt", decryptedString is nil and if I po unencryptedAsBytes in Xcode's console it displays this:

> "\aY|\376\347cD*\320NC\x14\x91C\x88\301\341z\xaca\x11\371

Any idea what is the problem here?

Comment: 4. Where is `AesCipherService` documented? Are you using the key as the IV, that is not secure. 5. Perhaps theIV is the first 16-bytes in the encrypted data, that is not  uncommon.

Comment: @zaph AesCipherService is part of the Apache crypto library https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/crypto/AesCipherService.html. The java part of the code is written not by me but by a server developer, I am trying to write the Objective-C part to decrypt what they have encrypted. The code I've posted above is my go at re-creating what they have done in condensed format to try to re-create the problem in a more manageable way. They are using AesCipherService as above i.e they are not setting the IV etc. explicitly and thus the AesCipherService defaults are being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java encryption code generates a random IV and prefixes the encrypted with it. In order to decrypt the IV is split from the encrypted.

In hex:

```
key:       32454531463130323132414444344245  
iv:        479501A4FDF46235FD01ED87A0F6F646 (first 16 binary bytes of the full encryption)  
encrypted: B7E2E6B40963677469CD7ECDA217E40E (rest of binary bytes of the full encryption)  
decrypted: 7465787420746F20656E6372797074
```

> Code:

```
NSData* fullEncrypted       = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString: @"R5UBpP30YjX9Ae2HoPb2Rrfi5rQJY2d0ac1+zaIX5A4="  options: 0];
NSData *ivData = [fullEncrypted subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, kCCBlockSizeAES128)];
NSData *encryptedData = [fullEncrypted subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(kCCBlockSizeAES128, fullEncrypted.length-kCCBlockSizeAES128)];
NSLog(@"ivData:          %@", ivData);
NSLog(@"encryptedData:   %@", encryptedData);

NSData *keyData = [@"2EE1F10212ADD4BE" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"keyData:         %@", keyData);

NSMutableData *unencryptedData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:encryptedData.length];
size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES,
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyData.bytes, keyData.length,
                                      ivData.bytes,
                                      encryptedData.bytes, encryptedData.length,
                                      unencryptedData.mutableBytes, unencryptedData.length,
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Success");

    unencryptedData.length = numBytesDecrypted;
    NSLog(@"unencryptedData: %@", unencryptedData);

    NSString *decryptedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unencryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"decryptedString: %@", decryptedString);
}
```

> Output:

```
ivData:          479501a4 fdf46235 fd01ed87 a0f6f646  
encryptedData:   b7e2e6b4 09636774 69cd7ecd a217e40e  
keyData:         32454531 46313032 31324144 44344245  
Success  
unencryptedData: 74657874 20746f20 656e6372 79707400  
decryptedString: text to encrypt
```

Comment: Totally awesome! Can't thank you enough, I've been stuck on this for literally days. How did you determine that the random IV was being prepended to the encrypted data?

Comment: Because that is common and theencrypted data was one block longer than it should be. Also the ObjC code defaults to CBC mode and an IV was needed. Of course I first made a guess about encodings that was wrong. <g>

Comment: BTW, here is a neat [AES converter](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=32454531463130323132414444344245&iv=479501A4FDF46235FD01ED87A0F6F646&input=B7E2E6B40963677469CD7ECDA217E40E&mode=cbc&action=Decrypt&output=B47CF26CD2992D0A765D1731AB4B2904), note the trailing 01 in the output data, that is the padding.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Hi why did you add + kCCBlockSizeAES128 to the length of the unencryptedData when its allocated?

Comment: Right, that was by habit of writing encryption code, not decryption only code. I removed it. It is needed for encryption to allow for padding.